# Jmeter Crashes when opening a step with a Base64 encoded image

Tags: base64, macbookpro

I'm running Jmeter on a MacBook Pro, which runs absolutely fine normally. But as soon as I try and view a step with a Base64 image it crashes and won't respond any further.
I was able to work on the script ok previously but its started to recently struggle recently.
Is there anything I can do to help Jmeter run better? My Mac should be more than capable. I created the scripts on it, a month or so ago, I just need to make a few edits now.

Opening a step in a script with a Base64 image, Jmeter crashes.